# Are there Reinforcement Learning algorithms speciallized for the case gamma=0?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

I have a Reinforcement Learning problem where the optimal policy does not depend on the next state (ie gamma equals 0). I think this means that I only need an efficient exploration algorithm.

I know that *contextual bandits* are specialized for this situation, except they only work for discrete action space, and I still need my policy network to make complex decisions (train a Deep neural networks, whereas most contextual bandits algorithms I found learn linear policy decisions).

Therefore I am looking for algorithms, or ideally a python library, that solves RL for continuous action spaces when gamma=0.

Many Thanks,

Comment: Maybe *active learning*? The theoretical question would be on-topic on https://ai.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't know if deep active learning would work, because there is still an environment such that we can not trace how the reward is computed.

Comment: Does this mean your episode length is 1 step? If thats the case you can run any RL algorithm with episode length of 1, just save the final state at the end of the episode and initialize the next episode with the initial state being equal to that final state from previous episode.

Comment: Yes I agree that this would work. But it does not seem that there are algorithms specialized for this use case.